# No database found!! mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
     //require_once("../StoredProcedure/connect.php");
  $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error);
  mysql_select_db("politicalforum",$conn); 

 function updateThread($threadID, $content) 
 {
     mysql_query("UPDATE threads
                  SET content='$content'  
                  WHERE thread_id=$threadID") ;
    // $res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
     mysql_close();
 }
```

I get this each time..what am I doing wrong?

> No database selected.

I am calling that function from an outside file...like this..

```
if(isset($_GET['threadID']) && isset($_POST["reply"]) && isset($_POST['textareas']))
   {

        updateThread($_GET['threadID'], $_POST['textareas']); 

       $postValid=TRUE;
   }
```

Comment: The database selection must happen from inside the function. You might want to consider making a class.

Comment: Did you check the result of `mysql_select_db`? What was it?

Comment: @Truth: Why's that then?

Comment: Yeah, most likely your select_db fails

Comment: is that function called twice? the second invocation would not work, since the first killed the connection with `mysql_close()`.

Comment: No, my bad. But you still probably want to make a class and drop the `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: it is called once but there is another     require("../StoredProcedure/connect.php"); outside the file..so basically, I include mysql_db_select twice... but even when I use it twice it doesnt work

Comment: I think you were right,,about the two calls to the same function. It seems to no longer throw the mistake..but why is that? why cant I call the funciton twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection is likely going out of scope, causing the mysql_query to run against the context's database object which doesn't exist by the time `updateThread` fires.

In this case you need to pass the connection into the `mysql_query` function inside `updateThread`. Architecturally there are two ways you can go about this:

1) Open and close the connection inside your `updateThread` function:

```
function updateThread($threadID, $content) 
{
   $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error);
   mysql_select_db("politicalforum",$conn); 
   mysql_query("UPDATE threads
                SET content='$content'  
                WHERE thread_id=$threadID", $conn) ;
   mysql_close($conn);
   $conn = null;
}
```

2) Pass the connection as a variable to updateThread, in case you want to use the same connection in other functions. PHP will automatically close and dispose your MySQL connection when the script finishes:

```
function updateThread($threadID, $content, $conn) 
{
   mysql_query("UPDATE threads
                SET content='$content'  
                WHERE thread_id=$threadID", $conn) ;
}
```

Comment: +1 for your 2nd solution. I don't think its clever to open and close connections all the time, so I'd never do (1).

Comment: In this case it would certainly seem better to create the connection once and then pass it in as a parameter